# decidability about NFA accepting an input

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

Let A = {(B,w) | B is an NFA that accepts w}. To prove that N is a decidable language,

M = "on input (B,w) where B is NFA and w is a string, simulate B on w. If B accepts w, accept. Otherwise, reject"

Is this a false proof? The proof from the textbook says that I have to convert NFA into equivalent DFA but I'm not sure why this would be necessary. Is it not possible to simulate NFA directly without conversion?

Comment: Do you know how to simulate a NFA on w?  How would you do that?  How would you determine whether it accepts or not?

Comment: I haven't thought about it but I guess if deterministic TM can implement non-deterministic TM, why not NFA?

Answer (score 2):

The textbook probably suggests you convert into a DFA because  it is easier to simulate a DFA than to simulate a NFA and determine whether the DFA accepts the word w.  This is trickier on a NFA (but still possible, if you know how).

Comment: Thanks. Also, does "simulating" something mean that the TM is going to run it (like provoking a function call inside a function), or TM is going to mimic the behaviour of that machine?